# Remove default PasswordValidator from Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity

I've created my own `PasswordValidator` and add it to the IdentityBuilder by using `services.AddIdentity<, >().AddPasswordValidator<>()`.
This adds my PasswordValidator on top of the default one, so the password will be checked by both. (not what I need).

How can I remove the default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddIdentity` only adds the default `PasswordValidator` implementation if one hasn't already been registered. Because of this, you can add your custom implementation *before* calling `AddIdentity`:

```
services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator<YourUser>, YourPasswordValidator>();
services.AddIdentity<YourUser, YourRole>(...);
```

In this case, only `YourPasswordValidator` gets registered.